# Microsoft CA Problem for Windows 10 Clients with Wireshark Installed

Tags: certificate, wireshark

This is a most bizarre scenario, but hoping someone else has ran into this at some point to shed some light.

We are in the process of migrating to a new host Microsoft CA service. There are CA proxies that point to the actual CA's that are hosted in the vendors SAAS. An enrollment service is registered in our AD PKI Services configuration and points to the gateways residing on our network. Like all MS CA enrollment services it leverages RPC for communications between certificate clients and the gateway server.

If we run the command: certutil -config "CA_GATEWAYSERVER\CA_NAME" -ping on a Windows 10 PC that never had Wireshark installed it works fine. If we run it on a Windows 10 PC that Wireshark installed at any point in the past it fails by timing out with an RPC server unavailable error. This occurs even if we uninstall Wireshark along with ensuring the NPCAP/Nmap adapter is removed.

Windows servers with Wireshark do not have this problem.

Comment: I've been able to narrow down to the issue to a silent install of Wireshark that doesn't install npcap due to their goofy licensing model and installing Nmap 7.70. Looks like the NMap install is the root cause for some reason. Even uninstalling NMap doesn't restore it to a functional state.

Comment: I've been able to narrow down the issue to the NPCap module that's included in the NMap install.